Is it possible to make grub import a grub.cfg file and load it?
Imagine the scenario:
You are at the grub prompt for any failure reason (example a USB stick made only for BIOS and you are on EFI). This USB stick is correct and has some accessible disks to run linux.
But as you are not in the graphic menu, you would have to type ALL commands manually. The grub "LS" even shows your grub.cfg file in a grub folder of the USB and I wonder if grub could "import" this grub.cfg file and load it's menus, avoiding typing a lot.
Does anyone know how ?

Grub rescue is different code to what occurs in grub; grub rescue being limited to 512 bytes (including pointer to where the later stages of grub are; rescue being run if those pointers are invalid)  If you're asking about grub rescue; it cannot access the file-system is its a boot loader & appears when file-system can't be found (512 bytes doesn't allow a easy to use GUI to be available).

To load a file and have grub execute its content, the command is configfile
configfile grub.cfg

Not sure this will be useful though as you're on BIOS key on an EFI system...

Thank you. If I type the cmds, linux images load  and work perfectly, I am gonna try your tip
